# Simple csv import using concurrency

Tags: haskell

I try to solve this academic use case: parse a csv file and insert data in database with multithreading.

In Java, I wrote a solution which uses the main thread to read the data into a collection and then run 8 tasks concurrently to insert the data in database. With my 8 core machine, it does the job in almost 60s for a 1 million lines csv file (2 columns: title and price).

Then I try to write equivalent in haskell (with my beginner skills):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO 
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Text (Parser)
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
import Data.Int
import Control.Concurrent.Async

line :: Parser (Text,Text)
line = do
  title  <- many $ noneOf ","
  oneOf ","
  price <- many $ digit
  return (pack title,pack price)

file :: Parser [(Text,Text)]
file = line `endBy` newline

parseCsv :: SourceName -> Text -> Either ParseError [(Text,Text)]
parseCsv = parse file

parseCsvF :: FilePath -> IO (Either ParseError [(Text,Text)])
parseCsvF path = fmap (parseCsv path) $ TIO.readFile path 

connectDB :: IO Connection
connectDB = connect (ConnectInfo { connectHost="localhost", connectPort=5432, connectUser="parser", connectPassword="parser", connectDatabase="parser"}) 

insertComic :: Connection -> (Text,Text) -> IO Int64 
insertComic conn (title,price) = execute conn "INSERT INTO comics (title, price) VALUES (?,?)" [unpack title , unpack price]  

main = do
  conn <- connectDB
  input <- parseCsvF "data.csv"
  let (Right x) = input
      inserts = Prelude.map (insertComic conn) x
      asyncs = Prelude.map async inserts
      waiters = Prelude.map waitForIt asyncs
  sequence waiters


waitForIt :: IO (Async Int64) -> IO Int64
waitForIt x =  x >>= \v -> wait v
```

```
ghc -threaded injector.hs -o injector
./injector +RTS -N8
```

unfortunately it is very slow (several minutes...)

I guess I didn't use Async correctly. Could someone give me an example of solution to make this program using multithreading efficiently ?

Comment: Remove the irrelevant code please. Your java code will not help anyone examine your haskell code.

Comment: How are you using Control.Concurrent.Async? You should indicate what changes you made when using that library. Simply adding the import won't add multi threading, and we need to know what changes you did make.

Comment: This task sounds like it should be memory bandwidth constrained, not CPU constrained. Out of curiousity, how much did parallelization speed up the Java implementation (keeping caching constant)?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard done

Comment: @BjarturThorlacius In java without parallelization : 292s VS 64s with so a 4,5 factor.

Comment: @IzaakWeiss Sorry I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your code that it start db transaction for each line.

I suggest you to split your data into chunk and process whole chunk in one transaction.

Also it will help if you will insert multiple records in one `insert` statement.

**EDIT**

Another problem (biggest one) you use only one connection which make make your code effectively sequential, not paralel.

Also you read all your data to memory before processing it. You can improve performance here too.

Comment: thanks, I edit my question thanks to the hints you gave me.

Comment: You shouldn't edit question in this case. If you want to post your solution, just post it as separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

I put here a solution, probably not the best one but it easily achieve better performance than the java one with far less lines of code and without using specific multithreading mechanisms.
I use resource pool and chunk of 10000 lines for insertions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO 
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Text (Parser)
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
import Data.Int
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Data.Pool
import qualified Data.List.Split as Split
import System.CPUTime

line :: Parser (Text,Text)
line = do
  title  <- many $ noneOf ","
  oneOf ","
  price <- many $ digit
  return (pack title,pack price)

file :: Parser [(Text,Text)]
file = line `endBy` newline

parseCsv :: SourceName -> Text -> Either ParseError [(Text,Text)]
parseCsv = parse file

parseCsvF :: FilePath -> IO (Either ParseError [(Text,Text)])
parseCsvF path = fmap (parseCsv path) $ TIO.readFile path 

connectionInfo :: ConnectInfo
connectionInfo = ConnectInfo {
  connectHost="localhost",
  connectPort=5432,
  connectUser="parser",
  connectPassword="parser",
  connectDatabase="parser"}

myPool :: IO (Pool Connection)
myPool = createPool (connect connectionInfo) close 1 10 10

insertComic :: Pool Connection -> [(Text , Text)] -> IO Int64
insertComic pool comic = withResource pool (\conn -> insertComic' conn comic)

insertComic' :: Connection -> [(Text,Text)] -> IO Int64 
insertComic' conn comics = executeMany conn "INSERT INTO comics (title, price) VALUES (?,?)" comics  

main = do
  start <- getCPUTime
  pool <- myPool
  input <- parseCsvF "data.csv"
  let (Right allComics) = input
      chunks =  Split.chunksOf 10000 allComics
      inserts = [ insertComic pool chunk  | chunk <- chunks]
  sequence inserts
  end <- getCPUTime
  putStrLn $ show $ fromIntegral (end-start) / 10^12
```

```
ghc -threaded injector.hs -o injector
./injector +RTS -N8
```